# Python boto3 SNS email formatting

Tags: python, string, format, boto3

I have written a code in which I am using aws sns to send email notifications to stake holders via boto3 library.

My issue is that when I wrote the code, I used 4space (or tab) spacing between texts to make it more readable, but when viewing it as an email (gmail), it's showing completely unformatted.

What I need is a way to properly format my email messages

My code:

```
import boto3
def publish_to_sns(sub, msg):
    topic_arn = "<my sns arn>"
    sns = boto3.client("sns")
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Message=msg,
        Subject=sub
    )

def final_status(f_name, row_count, staged_row_count, status):
    sub = "Complete [{status}]: Process is complete".format(status=status)
    msg = """
        Process completed.

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Summary of the process:
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        File Name    :   {file_name}
        Status       :   {status}
        Error        :   N/A
        Rows Read    :   {r_read}
        Rows Staged  :   {r_staged}
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        """.format(file_name=f_name, r_read=row_count, r_staged=staged_row_count, status=status)
    publish_to_sns(sub, msg)
```

What I am seeing (the colons are not aligned):

[image]

Comment: Aligning text with spaces of course only works if there's a fixed width font. You need to use html tables.

Comment: Hi JamesZ, Could you direct me to a link where I could find an example for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve quite readable formatting by using a simple hack. What I did was I copied the whole string from my IDE, and paste it in my Gmail's (We are using Gmail suite) compose message window.

**Unformatted text in Gmail**
[image: Unformatted text in Gmail]

Then I formated the text to look readable:

**Formatted text in Gmail**
[image: Formatted text in Gmail]

Then I pasted the whole string back in my IDE.

**Formatted text in IDE**
[image: Formatted text in IDE]

And it worked!!!

The notifications seems more readable to stake holders now, and considering the limitation of SNS to send rich text messages, this seems to be a quite easy approach.

Comment: It looks like workaround for only your browser, untill something changes (font, CSS or something else).

Answer (score 2):

This should help you fix the spaces:

```
def final_status(f_name, row_count, staged_row_count, status):
sub = "Complete [{status}]: Process is complete".format(status=status)
msg = """
    Process completed.

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Summary of the process:
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {a:<20}    :   {file_name}
    {b:<20}    :   {status}
    {c:<20}    :   N/A
    {d:<20}    :   {r_read}
    {e:<20}    :   {r_staged}
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    """.format(a='File Name', b = 'Status', c = 'Error', d = 'Rows Read', e = 'Rows Staged', file_name=f_name, r_read=row_count, r_staged=staged_row_count, status=status)
print(sub)
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[boto3](/questions/tagged/boto3)** **[email](/questions/tagged/email)**

For print statements in **[python](/questions/tagged/python)**, you can use white spaces to control the alignment of text. Here are two options:

1. Right-aligning [string](/questions/tagged/string) with a minimum width of 12 characters: `string:>12` or `string.rjust(12, ' ')`.
2. Left-aligning [string](/questions/tagged/string) with a minimum width of 12 characters: `string:<12` or `string.ljust(20, ' ')`.

However, when writing [emails](/questions/tagged/emails) for **[ms](/questions/tagged/ms)**-**[outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook)**, white space usage may differ due to potential character width issues.

If you need to write email bodies using Python and send them via **[aws](/questions/tagged/aws)**-**[sns](/questions/tagged/sns)** to **[microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft)** **[outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook)**, here's an approach to consider.

Here is the sample email body expected output.

```
[Date & Time]

Hello Everyone,

As part of our automation......The following list of files has been successfully uploaded......at xyz.com.

##     File size  File Name
01.        26598  test/Action.txt
02.       223750  test/Results.zip
03.      1970507  test/lambda/test.csv
. 
. 
.
60.     20993227  test/New_.jpg

Please review the uploaded.....
....
....
Best regards,
xyz
```

Let's assume you have the file details stored in a [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary) named `dict_all_file`.

```py
msg = '''
[Date & Time]

Hello Everyone,

As part of our automation process, we have important information to share. The following list of files has been successfully uploaded to xyz.com:

##           File size   File Name

'''
#
# '12' Max length character need for size, 
# len(str(value[0])) legth of file size from first iterm of dict values.
# '2' * ' ' --> double white space (for rest of character out of 12.)
#

Msg='\n'


file_size = f"{(12-len(str(value[0])))*2*' ')}{File size}"

msg+= f"## {file_size}  File Name"

for  k, v from in dict_all_file.items(): # dict with key as number of file and value with file size and file name.
    fix_size = f"{(12-len(str(value[0])))*2*' '}{value[0]}"
    MSG += f"\n\t {i:02d}.{fix_size}  {value[1]}"



MSG+= """Please review the uploaded files .......
.
.
Best regards,
xyz"""
'''

# Other code for sending the email via AWS SNS
```

In the provided code, the email body is generated using a combination of formatted strings and a loop over the dict_all_file dictionary. The file details, including the file size and file name. You can adjust the code and formatting according to your specific requirements.

This approach should help with writing emails for Microsoft Outlook while using Python and AWS SNS for delivery.

Hope this helps!